# I couldn't run container which one I created from live OS

Tags: linux, docker

I created a tar file of live centOS with:

```
tar --numeric-owner \
    --exclude=/proc \
    --exclude=/sys \
    --exclude=/mnt \
    --exclude=/var/cache \
    --exclude=/usr/share/doc \
    --exclude=/tmp \
    --exclude=/var/log \
    -zcvf /mnt/rhel7-base.tar.gz /
```

and then run
`cat rhel7-base.tar.gz | docker import - rhel7/01`
to load it into docker. It finished without an error and I can find it with
`docker images` command. Finally, i tried to run it `docker run -i -t rhel7/01` (also without -i,-t switches), but nothing result

```
[root@vhp~]# docker run rhel7/01
[root@vhp~]#
```

I'm wondering if any one corrects me.

Comment: see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/

Comment: thanks, but it is for debian base, and i'm using rpm.

Comment: Very good question, could you also explain why you want to create image from your OS? Do you want to run whole OS from docker or just one service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but it seems that you're missing command for docker to execute inside your image, try:

```
[root@vhp~]# docker run -it rhel7/01 bash # this should drop you into bash inside docker container
```

Also you can check if container is running with `docker ps -a`

Answer (score 0):

It better you pull centos image from official docker repo,then configure according to your use and then push  image to a registry.It is easy and simple.

docker push imagename

Comment: this is one way, it has some problem,for example some linux command did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Dockerfile like this:

```
#- pull base image.
FROM centos:latest
#- setting locale
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

#- add for terminal
ENV TERM xterm
```